# Dart database abstraction layer

Tags: database, flutter, dart, orm

Is there a Dart/Flutter equivalent of Django's database abstraction layer? It's more convenient to deal with objects than manual SQL queries.

Answer (score 1):

I guess what you are referring to is [Django's ORM](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/topics/db/models/).

There are ORMs for Dart, but none does currently is as complete as Django (which  has been in development for 16 years already).

That being said, there are quite a few ORM packages on Dart ([pub.dev search for ORM](https://pub.dev/packages?q=orm)).

Beware that:

- Some are abandoned but some are maintained.
- Not all work outside of mobile (no desktop or web support)
- Not all are null-safe (though this applies mostly to the abandoned ones).
- Most only work with SQLite

You may want to look at (I have no direct experience with those):

- [drift](https://drift.simonbinder.eu/), works for SQLite and has experimental PostgreSQL support.
- [sqfentity](https://pub.dev/packages/sqfentity) has an API similar to Django Managers (the `.objects` thing). Also SQLite

The current lack of ORMs for server based databases (mariadb, postgresql, ...) maybe due to the fact that Dart is not that much used in the backend (this may change as flutter gains popularity).

Regardless, if you want something similar to Django always search for ORM, not database abstraction.